# R- using gsub in a udf

Tags: r, string, gsub

im trying to create a udf to find and replace a bunch of different strings in a   few data frames. Example:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c("AA","BB","CC"))
y <- data.frame(b = c("AB","BC","CD"))
```

If I do the calls manually (like below) it works fine

```
x$a %<>% 
  gsub("A", "", .) %>% 
  gsub("B", "", .)
```

to give me - `("", "", "CC")` and `("","C","CD")` respectively

But if i do it within a UDF like so:

```
col <- function(var) {
var %<>% 
  gsub("A", "", .) %>% 
  gsub("B", "", .)
}

col(x$z)
```

It doesnt work. Is there a reason why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign it to the column as below

```
y$b = col(y$b)
```

If you just call `col(y$b)`, it does not store it in the actual dataframe `y` due to the function scope, ie. `var` is only available within function `col` and so if you want to take `var` out of function `col`, you need to assign it to a local variable